# In Jquery is there a way to access the text in a dragged div on drop, if I am unable to set an id or any other unique identifier?

Tags: jquery

In Jquery is there a way to access the text in a dragged div on drop, if I am unable to set an id or any other unique identifier?

I am a little new to the langage, let me know if you need any other details other than the basic question in the title.

Comment: In general: put all information for your question in the body. That might mean you have to copy stuff from the title, but it is much easier to read a question that way.

Comment: Went ahead and edited as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you can use the "target" element you find in the "event" object of the event handler.

Comment: Ok, using event.target I was able to get the target's inner html (where I was dropping it to) but not the inner html from the div I am dropping, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Indeed it appears that jQuery does not offer that information on arbitrary objects. It appears to be possible for dragged files, but not for DOM elements. You will have to use jQuerys "draggable" extension for this. Sorry.